# How to install cv_bridge?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!
I am running ros jade on Ubuntu14.04 with opencv3.2. I meet a problem with cv_bridge, as below:
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_highgui.so.2.4, needed by /opt/ros/jade/lib/libcv_bridge.so, may conflict with libopencv_highgui.so.3.2
So I think I have to recompile the cv_bridge package or vison_opencv package.
I have download the newest vison_opencv package, but I do not know how to use it or install it. So can anyone tell me how to do this?
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262329/how-to-install-cv_bridge?/) by [ToughMind](https://answers.ros.org/users/30487/toughmind/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-05-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A most simple one would be installed from the Ubuntu terminal:

sudo apt-get install ros-(ROS version name)-cv-bridge

sudo apt-get install ros-(ROS version name)-vision-opencv

It would automatically download from the Debian and installs the latest version (basically update from the old version if you already have one) in the system.

Otherwise,  visit the official ROS page of that required package and download the zip file. Move the extracted package inside the catkin workspace and install it.

I hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [vignesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26161/vignesh/) with karma: 101 on 2017-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ToughMind](https://answers.ros.org/users/30487/toughmind/) on 2017-05-24**:
I have tried this. In my situation, it doesn't work. I have soled this in another way^_^

**Comment by [iomh](https://answers.ros.org/users/48826/iomh/) on 2020-01-09**:
you should say how you solved it! @ToughMind

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have solved this problem by just using cmake to install the download cv_birdge package.

```
cmake
make
sudo make install
```

Then in my cmakelists, i have to add below sentence:

```
set(cv_bridge_DIR /usr/local/share/cv_bridge/cmake)
```

---

Originally posted by [ToughMind](https://answers.ros.org/users/30487/toughmind/) with karma: 21 on 2017-05-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1